# android popup layout over the whole screen

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Popup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="This is a simple popup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml layout for popup. But i want that this layout is almost over the whole screen not just so small. How can i extend it? I call it by the code.

Comment: Show us the code. How do you call it?

Comment: are you using dialog as your pop up?

Comment: use `match_parent` in height and width of `LinearLayout` and post the dialog code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

in `LinearLayout`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainAppActivity.this, R.style.PopupDialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
Button cancelButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Put this in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="PopupDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></style>
```