# Android Dialog like WeChat

Tags: android, customdialog

[image]

Has anyone know how to create a dialogbox like the picture showing above?

1. Rounded corner.
2. Transparent background.
3. No title, buttons, border.
4. Fade-in -- delay for 5 seconds -- fade out.

*I have seen toast, popup window, dialog, alert dialog, which of these best suit the above? :)

---

It would be nice if some code snippet could be provided, I'm fairly new to android :)

Comment: Create image in photoshop with rounded corners and transaprent then set it as background to your popup window

Comment: +1 popup window? can you guide me with code for this window? Sorry I'm fairly new to android.

Comment: Check my answer...I have given background for you,use that for your layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom dialog check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2fd686/androd-dialogs/

```
 private void createCustomDialog(){
        //Create a dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        //Set its layout
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
        //Set the title
        dialog.setTitle("This is custom layout");
        //Make it cancelable
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //We need to dismiss the dialog so we add a listener to the ok button
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

For the dark alpha background you can create a drawable. Below code will give you a semi transparent background with round corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
      <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#AA000000"
                    android:endColor="#AA000000"
                    android:angle="-90"
                    android:type="linear"
                    />
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

For the auto hide part you can use

```
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
anim.setDuration(300);
anim.setStartOffset(5000);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setFillAfter(false);

myView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: <corners android:radius="10dp" /> This is for rounded corners

Comment: How would I define the custom_dialog_layout?Just LinearLayout with background?

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473222/android-popup-layout-over-the-whole-screen/15473454#15473454 for a transparent theme for your dialog

Comment: I see, but myView can't be known as 'view' right? I cant startAnimation() dialog.

Comment: yes you are right, maybe the right approach should be a popup(view overlay) or a custom Toast notification(will auto hide no need for animation).

Comment: Actually this is some kind like 'You are correct' dialog box, and once it dismissed, it will move on to other activity, i think alertbox best to use in this situation right?

Comment: you can use custom Dialog but for auto dismissing it you will have to use a TimerTask

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem at all. Just create 9nth patch drawable with delays and fading and put it as bg for the dialog.

Comment: Ic, how can I automate delays like for 5seconds.

Comment: you can use TimerTask method to check after some delay.which will execute your method after delay whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Create XML with with your desired Content and then set transparent image to that

I am providing you image, use this

and the

Declare field of type PopupWindow.
PopupWindow popup;

inflate your layout here

```
 View v = inflatter.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
```

set your layout  to the popup window

```
v1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int height1 = v1.getMeasuredHeight();
popup= new PopupWindow(v, (int) (width * 0.8), height1, true);
 popup.showAtLocation(mainlayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

`mainlayout` is your activity view group

this is the piece of code that I have used in my app.

[image: Transparent Backgrouund]

Example I have used something like this in my app

[image: popup example]

Comment: +1 What would be the difference of working this on dialog and popup window?

Comment: @Roylee When you use dialog you can make the parent activity layout blur, but it is not possible when you use popup window. But using popup window is simple and you can position your popup window the specified position on the screen, but it is not possible incase of dialog

Comment: Great answer, and know I know the difference :) thanks @Pragnani

Answer (score 1):

Custom Toast would do everything for you, just prepare your xml and set it to Toast, here is a sample:

```
public class CustomToast {

public CustomToast(Context ctx, CharSequence text) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);

    TextView txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
    txt.setText(text);

    Toast myToast = new Toast(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 100);
    myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    myToast.setView(layout);
    myToast.show();
    }

}
```